# Uploading files to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm trying to store images for my user profiles on firebase hosting.  Currently, the files are hosted on S3 and that's fine, but I realized Firebase comes with 10gigs of free hosting.  I'm getting a CORS error when trying to upload to the my site.  Can someone let me know which configuration needs to be set in my firebase.json file to allow uploads to a specific directory. myfirebase10.firebaseapp.com/img

```json
"firebase": "myfirebase10",
"public": "app",
"ignore": [
"firebase.json",
".*",
"**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [ {
    "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
    } ]
}, {
    "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
    "destination": "/img",
    "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value" : "*"
    } ]
}, {
    "source" : "404.html",
    "headers" : [ {
        "key" : "Cache-Control",
        "value" : "max-age=300"
    } ]
} ]
}
```

Comment: I'd say keep it on s3. it's better.

Comment: As far as I know Firebase hosting doesn't implement access control in the way you seem to want it. You'll either have to give everyone access to the entire application or find another place to host those files. https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html

Comment: The code for the Firebase command line tools (which you use to deploy your app to Firebase hosting) is available on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/tree/master/lib. Might be worth checking there to see if there are any openings for user-based access to specific directories.

Comment: Thanks FrankvanPuffelen , lombausch !  I will take a look at the tools

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to find a solution.  Since I already had it working with S3, that's what I'm using.